# Why am I unable to find my desired environment variable functionality on Win7?

Tags: javacard

[image]

And, in the path section I have:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;
%JC_HOME%\bin\;
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

And, this is my `E:\JavaDevTools\java_card_kit-2_2_2\bin` looks like:

[image]

Then, why isn't this command working?

[image]

Another problem is, I have my Java SDK like this:

[image]

Then, why is this command showing the version of JRE, not JDK?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why your path isn't working, but Java on windows doesn't use JAVA_HOME to find the JVM, instead is uses a registry entry to point to the "current" JRE

Comment: Why close-vote and down-vote?

Comment: @BROY Maybe because it seems that this is not a programming question.(although it is related with programming). You must ask this kind of questions in the https://wwww.superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First problem:**

Put the extracted address of JavaCard `bin` directory in the *PATH* environment variable. i.e replace `%JC_HOME%\bin` with `E:\JavaDevTools\java_card_kit-2_2_2\bin` and it will works fine.

**Second problem:**

The origin of this problem is answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/741068/incorrect-java-version-on-command-prompt) :

> When installing a public JRE (used by the Java plugin), a **java.exe**
>   file is also created in `C:\WINNT\system32 (IIRC)`. It's probably this
>   java command that is executed, since `C:\WINNT\system32` comes before
>   the JDK/bin directory in your PATH.
>
> Put the JDK/bin directory at the beginning of the PATH.

Comment: then, what is the need for user-side variables?

Comment: @BROY Unfortunately I have no idea!

Comment: You can make them system wide variables, but it is very conceivable that you would not want to mess with the Java runtime that you use for applications. Personally I'm always using the Java version that was mentioned by the JC specs, and the most up to date one for my off card applications.